# How to convert powerpoint pptx file to ppt file programmatically without powerpoint installed?

Tags: powerpoint

How can I convert a pptx file to a ppt file programmatically. This happens on a web server that does not have PowerPoint installed.
I'm after a free solution preferably.

I may consider installing PowerPoint on the server if it is not possible but I'm concerned about the scalability of that solution. I wouldn't want the server to be struggling because multiple conversions are in progress...

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with forcing people to install the compatibility pack from Microsoft?

Comment: it's not always possible to get clients to install compatibility pack. Some IT departments are very tight about what users can install on their machine...

Comment: The server wouldn't struggle under the load of multiple PPT instances because PPT itself will allow only one instance.  It would be up to you to feed it one file at a time to convert.  And re your question of Shaunak, yes, the code provided would require PPT to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

You could install OpenOffice Impress (Libre Office Impress) on the server, maybe it can do the document conversion.

I hear that in OpenOffice, there are python APIs avalaible, and maybe more, even a VBA clone.

It is probably not possible to convert from the command line like this,

```
ooimpress -infile "mydoc.pptx" -outfile "mydoc.ppt"
```

In any case, the conversion will probably not be perfect. If your pptx files contain embedded OLE documents, expect problems.

SImple slides with bulleted lists and some simple graphics objects (circles, arrows, Raster Graphics files such as gifs) are less likely to be a problem.

Here are some links to openoffice forum-threads with similar problems.

.doc to .pdf, all command-line?
http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=5513

Help! - Simple command line conversion of Word doc to XML
http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=7242

Answer (score 0):

The presentation object has a SaveAs method that can do this. For instance,
for saving the active presentation as a .ppt file, the following code would
do the job:

```
ActivePresentation.SaveAs "FileName.ppt", ppSaveAsPresentation
```

Reference:

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/programmatic-conversion-pptx-into-ppt-t3339221.html